# Is it possible to get the http requests spotify does?

Tags: http, https

So, I just got spotify and I was wondering if it's possible to get the http request the application does...

Comment: Yep. http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can either ask your browser to log its HTTP traffic (e.g. in Firefox, the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) addon provides very convenient logging of the headers), or you can just capture your network traffic (with `tcpdump`/[`windump`](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/)) and evaluate that, e.g. with Wireshark.